# Easy way to redirect page when site not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

We have a regular `asp.net` website. I started debugging several errors, so the website cannot be used (but is not down). Since the default page is not `Default.aspx` and users are used to going directly to `Main.aspx`, if anyone goes to http://network:1332/Main.aspx, the person should be redirected to Issues.htm.

Is there an easy to do this without having to alter Main.aspx or write any code? Maybe change `web.config` or some `IIS 6` configuration?

I just don't want anyone to use the website even though the site is available for use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have an ASP.NET web application site, and you place a text file
>   named "app_offline.htm" in the root of the site, all requests to that
>   website will redirect to that app_offline.htm file. Basically, if you
>   need to take an entire ASP.NET site offline, you can place some nice
>   message in that file.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1152788.aspx?Put+website+in+maintenance+mode

Be warned you too will be directed to the maintenance page, so if you're debugging in production this could make things more difficult.

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url Rewrite Module to IIS. Then you will be able to define your rewrite rules in web.config or using IIS Manager. Check this : https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module